# FloatingActionButton Taking extra spaces in pre-lollipop

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have added a `FloatingActionButton` for lollipop and above its perfectly ok but for below lollipop it is taking extra spaces sorrounding to it

xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="mini" />
```

screenshot of lollipop n above:
[image]

The `FloatingActionButton` here is taking the right amount of space but look at the second screen

screenshot of pre-lollipo:
[image]
Now take a look here how there is extra margin or extra blank spaces taken by the `FloatingActionButton`. How to resolve this issue.

Comment: I believe you need to use different dimens.xml files for lolipop and lower versions, because stuff like elevation (in your case fabSize and borderWidth) isn't correctly recognised on pre-lolipop versions

Comment: yes @slorangex i believe you are right because when i changed the elevation and the space also tends to change accordingly. i think diferent dimen.xml file for both lollipop n pre-lollipop containing different elevation may do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `FloatingActionButton` into `CoordinatorLayout` and all margins will be the same on all platforms. In this case the position of the button is adjusted by [FloatingActionButton.Behavior](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.Behavior.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This requires android support library v22.2.1, according to comments on [android issue 175330](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175330#c9)

Answer (score 4):

It is a known issue and it is due to extra margin. You can do it like below,

```
    //to fix margin issue/bug with pre lollipop version
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) floatingActionButton.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); // get rid of margins since shadow area is now the margin
        floatingActionButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
```

There is nothing fancy but just a bug.

[image]

[image]

Comment: just found out that it is due to the default elevation which is taking the extra spaces for pre-lollipop making the elevation 0 will remove the space.

Comment: yes it will but but the shadow is the taking the extra space here

Answer (score 0):

I've used negative margin to shrink the size of FAB on pre-lollipop devices but also keeping the shadow area around the button so view isn't ruined.

```
int dimen5dp = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dimen_5_dp);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) floatingActionButton.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(
            params.leftMargin,
            params.topMargin - ((int) (dimen5dp * 3.1)),      //Approximate factor to shrink the extra 
            params.rightMargin - ((int) (dimen5dp * 3.1)),    //spacing by the shadow  to the actual 
            params.bottomMargin - ((int) (dimen5dp * 3.1)));  //size of the FAB without a shadow
    floatingActionButton.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Also I've wrapped the FAB inside a LineaLayout with `app:useCompatPadding="false"` as such:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_expand"
        app:useCompatPadding="false"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below are images of the result on the left it's the pre-lollipop device and on the right is the lollipop and above device. I've used uiautomatorviewer and turned on layout bounds on device. Red dotted line are the bounds of the FAB button while purple line with blue corners are the bounds of the LinearLayout. In the case of the lollipop device, shadow of FAB is not taking extra space so it's bounds are exactly around the button without extra margins. While the pre-lollipop device, the shadow take extra space hence the FAB bounds will have margins around the button, but with negative margins set, the LinearLayout shrinks to the bounds of the button without the extra space added by the shadow.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp"
```

to your FloatingActionButton xml should work without altering the elevation.